# No carga la página al modificar enlace javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

Modificando un archivo de html tengo el siguiente botón de facebook.

```
<li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

Entiendo que `javascript:void(0)` bloquea cualquier función del botón, pero al querer sustituir lo anterior por el facebook correspondiente, **NO ME CARGA EL HTML** y se queda estático.

```
<li class="list-inline-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MYFB"><i class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

Revisando la consola me arroja error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http jquery.min.js:2 s://www.facebook.com/MYFB
```

El orden de los enlaces es el siguiente:

```
<!-- javascript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scrollspy.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SLIDER -->
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
    <script src="js/portfolio-filter.js"></script> 
    <!-- Contact -->
    <script src="js/contact.js"></script>
    <!-- Counter -->
    <script src="js/counter.init.js"></script>
    <!-- Switcher -->
    <script src="js/switcher.js"></script>
    <!-- Main Js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con `onclick`

```
<a onclick="location.href='https://www.facebook.com'"><i></i></a>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jonathan Orta solución definitiva¡